# Display a random image from an image field

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have an image field on my content type that can accept 5 images to be uploaded. I would like for just one of them (at random) to be displayed on my page. Is there a module that can create a display formatter that will do this? Or is there a way I can accomplish this in my page.tpl.php?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..

```
$imgCount = count($node->field_header_image[$node->language]) - 1; 

$randomNum = rand(0,$imgCount); echo $randomNum; 

echo file_create_url($node->field_header_image[$node->language][$randomNum]['uri']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give [Single Image Formatter](https://drupal.org/project/single_image) a try, from its drupal project page it allows you to define which image to display. Providing an index which will never exist (6 if you can upload up to 5 images) it will choose a random image. Sounds like it could do the job.